# What are the historical equivalents of cooperative storytelling like modern role-playing games?

Tags: middle-ages, ancient-history, cultural-history, medieval-china, medieval-japan

I understand the direct history of RPGs mostly coming from *Dungeons and Dragons*, which had grown out of the combat game *Chainmail*, but I am wondering if there were any close equivalents in older history. I am not looking for wargaming history, but earlier examples of similar cooperative storytelling. It seems even the ancient Egyptians had dice, so there is no technological barrier. Are cooperative storytelling games purely modern or is there an ancient equivalent?

Edit: I am in particular looking for games in which people sit down together and improv out a story for personal enjoyment. I have found examples of old war games (like chess) and we have theater. I have not found any examples of this group improv.

Comment: Could you edit your question to clarify where you've searched and what you found already, complete with links and references, and context if applicable? In particular, please let us know what you find missing or unclear about the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_role-playing_games) on the topic. This allows those who might want to answer to do so without needing to redo the work you've already done. You might find it helpful to review the site [tour] and [help] and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: How "*ancient*" is ancient? The possible *antecedents* are virtually any - and every - cooperative endeavour engaged in by humans since we evolved, from theatre troupes to Prussian *kriegspiel* to team sports. I'm intrigued by the question so not yet voting to close as too broad - but as written it really is too broad and needs to be clarified and focused .

Comment: I have not found any examples of communal improv. Perhaps I am not good enough at searching for things or perhaps there is nothing like it. 

@PieterGeerkens - I am looking for this particular activity. It seems strange that there are no references to it when everyone in the past had the technology to have RPGs.

Comment: The ancient and medieval equivalent would have been storytelling competitions like Boccaccio's _Decameron_ or East Asian poetry competitions, which sometimes involved following line for line. Usually style and allusion was awarded more than building up a character's stats as things went along, though.

Comment: Murderhobos aren't a common premodern trope. Eh... _heroic_ murderhobos, anyway.

Comment: Obligatory [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/593/).

Comment: Basically role-playing is just the children's game of "Let's Pretend", but with rules and dice because we've lost the imagination and trust of our childhood.

Answer (score 11):

This is only a partial answer (by challenging the frame) but way too long for a comment ...

- I believe that there will be no clear answer because wargaming and RPGs influenced each other in ways that make it difficult to separate them. Look at the early history of [Traveller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traveller_(role-playing_game)), for instance, and [Trillion Credit Squadron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traveller_Adventure_5:_Trillion_Credit_Squadron).
- When you put the focus on cooperative storytelling, how do you draw the line between a RPG with character sheet, dice, *and story elements*, and e.g. a game with [hand puppets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand_puppet) telling a story.
  For that matter, how about children creating cooperative adventures with [Playmobil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playmobil) figures or similar toys?

So, having said that, I nominate [dolls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doll#Early_history_and_traditional_dolls) even if I cannot confirm how the play unfolded. Make it 2000 BC, with play dolls at least from 100 AD.

Comment: I like how far you pushed this back, Check out [oldest known doll](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-5218061/Doll-unearthed-worlds-oldest-toy-collection.html) from 4500 years ago. Yes, newspapers aren't the best reference - but it's your answer not mine, so I'll let you  finish off the work.

Comment: Dungeons & Dragons is slightly older than Traveller, I think. Yeah, playing theater roles is as old as antiquity and there is no reason to assume that its precursors, be it childs play or entertainment, is not older. Like much older. Speculatively hypothetically. Could even be older than language. There is no way to tell with certainty.

Comment: @a_donda, one could try more restrictive definitions. A rules set for character generation, the ability to reuse **and improve** characters, different paths for characters to specialize, but some RPGs might not qualify under those restrictions. The presence of a **game master** distinct from the players. The presence of a **plot** to be played.

Comment: Perhaps to keep the definition restrictive we could say "An activity in which people got together improvising stories with each other, that was not ordered towards a larger performance." 

This would remove hand puppets and other theater practices, reading a play together, and a bard singing a story to everyone.

Comment: @o.m.: Ok, yeah that may at most extend it to play-like reconstruction of battles with tin figures, if the players need a referee to settle scores ... 18th century or so ?

Comment: @a_donda, that sounds like wargaming. The difference between a character and an interchangeable game piece is what makes the RPG.

Answer (score 1):

In the study of historical games there is a strong evidentiary bias towards those that used physical artifacts. A board for [*ur*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Game_of_Ur) or a drawing of [*senet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senet) probably predate evidence of a collaborative talking game. Those games have narrative structure, but the state of the game is represented by the placement of physical tokens instead of the use of language.

A major antecedent of role-playing games is [divination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divination), fortune telling. The activity can be more or less structured depending on context, but usually involves some kind of spiritual authority and ritual, and possibly introduces new information. All through the history of speech people have been asking each other's advice, and it wasn't far from there to the emergence of trusted elders, shamans, and gurus. Divination rituals include visiting an [oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythia), throwing [knucklebones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knucklebones), consuming [entheogens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entheogen), [tarot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarot), and [ouija](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouija). Some of these are more randomized (i.e. [cleromancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleromancy)) and some are more guided (e.g. [séance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9ance)).

Role-playing games combine the rituals of spiritual authority with the fantasy of board games and the chance of cleromancy. Perhaps the most analogous historical practice --- a guided, collaborative thematic adventure --- is an entheogenic drug trip led by a shaman. Fantasy, suggestibility, and struggle are all present. Archaeological evidence for prehistoric shamanistic trips may be thin, but ethnographic evidence suggests that many peoples brought spiritual drug rituals into the modern age.